# Android Rotation Animation off Axis

Tags: android, animation, rotation, android-animation, axis

Most of the time my Radar ImageView is rotating in Axis

But sometimes when the page reload or on Startup of my app the ImageView is rotating at the corner of its container.

http://i.imgur.com/rOujCf9.gifv

RotateCenter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="359"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"/>
</set>
```

In OnCreate()

```
Animation rotateRadarAnimationLooking = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_center);
lookingHostRadar.startAnimation(rotateRadarAnimationLooking);
```

radar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/looking_host_radar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        font="ProximaNovaRegular"
        android:id="@+id/looking_for_party_text"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/looking_host_radar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/accent_color_light"
        android:text="@string/looking_for_party"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

radar_layout.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/radar_relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_radar_home_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/shaped_button_height"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            <include layout="@layout/radar"/>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by setting a size of 100 dp to my radar.

I could also have done this

```
lookingHostRadar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobaLayoutListener() { 
​
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        lookingHostRadar.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
        lookingHostRadar.startAnimation(rotateRadarAnimationLooking);
    }   
}
```